# Tradeoff when estimating the variance of the autocorrelation estimator

Tags: variance, estimation, autocorrelation

## Autocorrelation estimator

Given a [wide-sense stationary process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity) $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ one can estimate its autocorrelation defined as $R[k]=\mathbb{E}[X_tX_{t+k}]$ from $N$ observations $\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N\}$ using the following unbiased estimator

$$
\begin{equation}
\hat{R}[k]=\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-k}X_iX_{i+k}
\end{equation}
$$

## My question

How does one estimate the variance of this autocorrelation estimator?

## Attempt using trajectories

Considering that we have $T\times N$ observations (or trajectories)

$$\left\{\{X_i^j\}\right\}=\left\{\{X_1^1,\ X_2^1,\ \dots,\ X_N^1\},\ \dots,\ \{X_1^T,\ X_2^T,\ \dots,\ X_N^T\}\right\}$$

the variance of our estimator is given by
$$
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Var}\left[\hat{R}[k]\right]=\frac{\sigma_{Y_k}^2}{T}
\end{equation}
$$

with $\sigma_{Y_k}^2=\mathrm{Var}[Y_k]$ the variance of $\{Y_t^k\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$, a new process defined by

$$
\begin{equation}
\{Y_t^k\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}=\left\{\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-k}X_{t+i}X_{t+i+k}\right\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}
\end{equation}
$$

from which we have $T$ iid observations $\{Y_1^k,\ \dots,\ Y_T^k\}$ ($T$ realisations of the autocorrelation estimate) with
$$
\begin{equation}
Y_j^k=\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-k}X_i^jX_{i+k}^j
\end{equation}
$$

An **estimator of the variance of the autocorrelation estimator** is then given using $\hat{s}_k^2$ the unbiased sample variance of $\{Y_t^k\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$,

$$
\begin{align}
\widehat{\mathrm{Var}}\left[\hat{R}[k]\right]&=\frac{\hat{s}_k^2}{T}\\
&=\frac{1}{T(T-1)}\sum_{j=1}^T\left(Y_j^k-\hat{R}[k]\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{T(T-1)}\sum_{j=1}^T\left(\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-k}\left(X_i^jX_{i+k}^j\right)-\hat{R}[k]\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

## The tradeoff

When sampling from the process $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$, if one wants to minimize the variance of the autocorrelation estimator with a fixed number of observations, there seems to be a tradeoff between the number of trajectories $T$ and the length of these trajectories $N$. Is there any known work on this topic? Also, are the above calculations correct?